# Ajax on html block in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to use Ajax in my Ruby on Rails 3 application. Problem is I want the Ajax link to surround a div tag. If possible I'd rather it be with jQuery rather than prototype. How would I accomplish this?

I would like a solution involving some rails type programing something like link_to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all add 'jquery-rails' gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then run `bundle install` and `rails g jquery:install`. That's all. Now you can work with jQuery.

Add a div into your view, for example:

```
<div id='ajax_div'><%= @article.title %></div>
```

Now you can include some javascript this way:

```
$(
  function(){
    $("#ajax_div").click(function(){
      $.ajax(...)
    }
  }
)
```

More about $.ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (you can use either $.post or $.get or $.getScript)

**UPD**

working with ajax through `link_to`

```
<%= link_to some_path, :remote => true do %>
  <div id='ajax_div'><%= @article.title %></div>
<% end %>
```

**FROM THE BEGINNING**

Let's create new rails application. From scratch. To show how ajax works. I won't test it, so here can be misstypes and mistakes.

- `rails new ajaxapp`
- `cd  ajaxapp`
- `rails g scaffold Comment body:text`
- `rake db:create`
- `rake db:migrate`
- `add gem 'jquery-rails' to Gemfile` => bundle install => rails g jquery:install

let's edit comments/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Listing comments</h1>

<%= link_to comments_path, :remote => true, :method => :post do %>
  <div>Click me to add random comment</div>
<% end -%>
<div id='comments'>
  <%= render @comments %>
</div>
```

_comment partial:

```
<p>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>
```

Now we will add app/views/create.js.erb file:

```
$("#comments").append("<%= escape_javascript( render @comment ) %>")
```

comments_controller create action:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.body = (0...50).map{ ('a'..'z').to_a.<<(" ")[rand(27)] }.join
  @comment.save
end
```

that's all. Now run `rails s`. Go to `localhost:3000/comments`.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a Rails way to do it using something like link_to type command

Comment: actually rails job is server-side job. and there is no instrument to handle ajax and DOM right in rails

Comment: that doesnt work, anyway where would it load the ajaxed content into?

Comment: of course it doesn't work. it is just an example. you should create and set your controller. Organize response etc. I'll try to show now all stack in my comment.